# Laravel Getting only certrain data from pivot table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using Laravel to query users that have a score ( row in eventscore table )
And i want to return all the users that have scores for the event with an ID of 3

Is it possible to only return the score of every user, found in the pivot table ( see results below )

[image]

This is the code i'm using

```
    $persons = Person::whereHas('eventscore', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', 3);
    })->with('eventscore')->get();

    return $persons;
```

Thank you!

Comment: So the questions is How to fetch eventscores with pivot `score=3` or How to fetch only pivot data? And this relation should be called `events` not `eventscore` to be meaningful btw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I indeed only want to fetch the score for this event.. so that's eventscore->pivot->score? Thanks!

Comment: Jarek? Still care to help me out? :) thanks

Comment: If you need only the score, I would suggest other relation (or even simple join) linking `Person` with the pivot table itself (`hasMany`). Tell me more, how you'd like to use it and what for, then I can give you more precise answer.

Comment: Well, I have a specific page for each event, the event ID is the (eventscore.id). So i would like to see the name, and the score of each person for that specific event. I hope this is clear? I think you're right about making a simpler query..

Comment: This is actually the only sql i need..    SELECT name, firstname, name
   FROM personen
   JOIN event_scores ON event_scores.person_id = personen.id
   WHERE event_id = 3

Comment: Try my answer, I think this will work best for you. You could in fact use that join, but what I showed is the Eloquent way - pick whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Person model

// accessor for easy fetching the score from the pivot model
public function getScoreAttribute()
{
  return ($this->pivot && $this->pivot->score)
    ? $this->pivot->score
    : null;
}

// example usage for the event's page (I assume participants is the relation)
$event = Event::with('participants')->find(3);

// somewhere in the view template
@foreach ($event->participants as $participant)
  {{ $participant->name }} - score: {{ $participant->score }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the getScoreAttribute? Does laravel automatically know this when you run $participant->score? Thanks for the answer! this is it ! :)