# Laravel listen for queries error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a listener for queries, as adviced by many people on stackoverflow. This is the syntax

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
    dd($query);
});
```

But i'm getting the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::listen()
```

I also attached a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Is it deprecated?

Comment: Do you happen to have a model called `Event` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other model or facades with name `Event` you should put it inside for example `app/start/local.php` and it should work out of the box:

I have it defined this way:

```
Event::listen(
    'illuminate.query',
    function ($sql, $bindings, $time) {
        $sql = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', "'%s'"), $sql);
        $full_sql = vsprintf($sql, $bindings);

        file_put_contents(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs'
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sql_log.sql', $full_sql . ";\n",
            FILE_APPEND);
    }
);
```

and it logs all queries to file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm still getting the same error.. Very weird! Not even with my simple version. It's like it doesn't know the listen() function

Comment: @MiguelStevens Are you sure you don't have any own class with name `Event` ? Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175060/laravel-getting-only-certrain-data-from-pivot-table it seems quite possible